# Does a third-generation iPod Touch support video compositions?

Tags: iphone, avfoundation, avvideocomposition

In my project I use AVVideoComposition, it only works on iPhone 3GS and iPhone 4. On iPods and iPhone 3 it returns exception that this library is not supporting by that device, so is anybody know did the new iPod touch supports that or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The third-generation iPod Touch should be supported, see the slides from [WWDC](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2010/) session 407:
[image]